# How to highlight folders with new files in IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I recently changed from eclipse to IDEA and i am wondering how to activate that function.

**More detailed:**
I activated 'Show directories with changed descendants' in Settings → Version Control → Subversion. If i modify a file, IDEA will change the text color of all folders from root to the folder containing this file and the file itself. So it is easy to browse into the folders where changes have been made.

If i add a new file to a folder, IDEA will only change the color of the file itself but will not change the folders above.

I found that the color is the one from files in 'Unknown' status in Settings  Editor → Colors & Fonts → File Status.

I am working with IDEA 2016.1.3 and SVN 1.9.4

**Question:** 
Is there any way to get the text color for folders changed when there are files in 'Unkown' state?

If not, is there anything similar to highlight folders with new files?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution i found is to add the file to SVN (CTRL + ALT + A). Then SVN knows that the file is a new one and folders are highlighted like they are if already known files have been changed.